# Call a chain of functions that return a status and an error message

Tags: ruby

I have a series of functions to call (`func1`, `func2` and `func3`). I want to call them in this order, and stop as soon as one fails.

If one function fails, I want this function to return an error message, so I can later print it.

How can I do this in ruby ?

I tried:

```
def func1
  return true, 'no error'
end

def func2
  return true, 'no error'
end

def func3
  return false, 'error in func3. Reason: ...'
end

def main
  # doesn't work, because an array always evaluates to true
  result = func1 && func2 && func3

  # stops at the first error, but doesn't return the error message
  result = func1[0] && func2[0] && func3[0]
  puts result.inspect
end
main
```

It could be done like this: (but I don't like the fact that that false is returned when the function succeeds ; and it's not clear what's being returned: a status or an error message?)

```
def func1
  return false
end

def func2
  return false
end

def func3
  return 'func 3 failed'
end

def main
  result = func1 || func2 || func3

  puts result.inspect
end
main
```

### Is there a more explicit way of doing this?

**Edit:** To clarify what I want:

```
 - if func1 fails,    func2 fails,    func3 fails:    error is: 'error in func1'
 - if func1 fails,    func2 succeeds, func3 fails:    error is: 'error in func1'
 - if func1 succeeds, func2 succeeds, func3 succeeds: there is no error
 - if func1 succeeds, func2 succeeds, func3 fails:    error is: 'error in func3'
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use exceptions in this case.

```
def func1
  true
end

def func2
  true
end

def func3
  raise "error in func3. Reason: ..."
end

def main
  result = func1 && func2 && func3
  puts "success: #{result}"
rescue => ex
  puts ex
end


main
# >> error in func3. Reason: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is the [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method!

If you have a `Test` class:

```
class Test
  def a1
    puts "all ok in a1"
  end

  def a2(fail=false)
    unless fail
      puts "all ok in a2"
    else
      raise "a2 error"
    end
  end

  def a3
    puts "all ok in a3"
  end
end
```

and an instance of `test` of `Test`, you can call the chained method as follows:

```
test.tap(&:a1).tap { |x| x.a2 }.tap(&:a3)
#=>all ok in a1
#=>all ok in a2
#=>all ok in a3
```

and

```
test.tap(&:a1).tap { |x| x.a2(true) }.tap(&:a3)
#=>all ok in a1
#=>RuntimeError: a2 error,
```